# Inconsistent results from prepared query to find last insert id

Tags: sql, db2, phpunit, db2-400

I am testing a query to find the last insert ID from an IBM DB2 database. (I discovered the hard way that inserting and then selecting the record that matches the insert's values is not at all a reliable way of getting the last insert ID!)

Usually, the insert will be the type that uses an autoincrement field `id` and I want to grab the last value; however, one table uses SSN (obviously not autoincremented) and this is the scenario I'm testing. (all tables use the same insert method)

The query looks like this:

`SELECT id FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO {table} ({fields}) VALUES (?,? ... ?))`

My problem is that sometimes I get a result from the select, and sometimes I don't get a result!

*The really weird thing is that if I don't use placeholders and just put in the raw values, it works!*

## The test

```
<?php
print "Loading 001_crudClassTest\n";
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require_once('testConfigSetup.php');
if(ENVIRONMENT != 'TEST') { die('YOU ARE NOT IN TEST ENVIRONMENT!  PROGRAM STOPPED!'); }


/**
 * Test basic CRUD functions using SelMaster
 */
class crudClassTest extends TestCase {


  public function __construct() {
    // construct is executed with EVERY test.
  }

  public function setUp() {
    // setUp is executed with Every test.  
    $this->m = new SelMaster(new TestDatabase);

  }


  public function testNewInsert() {

    $this->m->db->prepare("DELETE FROM {$this->m->db->library}.SelMaster");
    $this->m->db->execute();

    $data = array(
      array('id'=>'001110001','firstName'=>'Billy','lastName'=>'Batson','fullName'=>'Billy Batson'),
      array('id'=>'001110002','firstName'=>'Steve','lastName'=>'Rogers','fullName'=>'Steve Rogers'),
      array('id'=>'111110003','firstName'=>'Hank','lastName'=>'McCoy','fullName'=>'Hank McCoy'),
      array('id'=>'111110004','firstName'=>'Bruce','lastName'=>'Wayne','fullName'=>'Bruce Wayne'),
      array('id'=>'111110005','firstName'=>'Selina','lastName'=>'Kyle','fullName'=>'Selina Kyle'),
      array('id'=>'111110006','firstName'=>'Scott','lastName'=>'Summers','fullName'=>'Scott Summers'),
      array('id'=>'111110007','firstName'=>'Matthew','lastName'=>'Murdock','fullName'=>'Matthew Murdock'),
      array('id'=>'111110008','firstName'=>'Slade','lastName'=>'Wilson','fullName'=>'Slade Wilson'),
      array('id'=>'111110009','firstName'=>'Emma','lastName'=>'Frost','fullName'=>'Emma Frost'),
      array('id'=>'111110010','firstName'=>'Alan','lastName'=>'Scott','fullName'=>'Alan Scott'),
      array('id'=>'111110011','firstName'=>'Bruce','lastName'=>'Banner','fullName'=>'Bruce Banner'),
      array('id'=>'111110012','firstName'=>'Wally','lastName'=>'West','fullName'=>'Wally West'),
      array('id'=>'111110013','firstName'=>'Richard','lastName'=>'Reeds','fullName'=>'Richard Reeds','spouseId' => '3'),
      array('id'=>'111110014','firstName'=>'Barry','lastName'=>'Allen','fullName'=>'Barry Allen'),
      array('id'=>'111110015','firstName'=>'Ben','lastName'=>'Grimm','fullName'=>'Ben Grimm'),
      array('id'=>'111110016','firstName'=>'Peter','lastName'=>'Parker','fullName'=>'Peter Parker','spouseId' => '2'),
      array('id'=>'111110017','firstName'=>'Clark','lastName'=>'Kent','fullName'=>'Clark Kent','spouseId' => '1'),
      array('id'=>'111110018','firstName'=>'Carter','lastName'=>'Hall','fullName'=>'Carter Hall'),
      array('id'=>'111110019','firstName'=>'Martin','lastName'=>'Stein','fullName'=>'Martin Stein'),
      array('id'=>'111110020','firstName'=>'Dick','lastName'=>'Grayson','fullName'=>'Dick Grayson'),
      array('id'=>'111110021','firstName'=>'Luke','lastName'=>'Cage','fullName'=>'Luke Cage','spouseId' => '4'),
      array('id'=>'111110022','firstName'=>'Tony','lastName'=>'Stark','fullName'=>'Tony Stark','spouseId' => '5','contactId'=>'1')

    );

    foreach($data as $record) {
      list($keys,$placeholders,$vals) = $this->m->parametersForInsert($record);
      $query = sprintf(
        "SELECT %s FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO {$this->m->db->library}.selmaster (%s) VALUES(%s))",
        $this->m->map['id'],         // maps 'id' to 'SSN' 
        implode(',',$keys),          // fields, mapped to db field names in $this->m
        implode(',',$placeholders)   // ? for each field/value pair
        );
      print "\n$query  " . implode(',',$vals);
      $this->m->db->prepare($query); // PDO-like wrapper for ODBC
      $this->m->db->execute($vals);

      if($row = $this->m->nextRecord()) {  // fetchObject wrapper
        print "\n";
        print_r($row);  // => should yield results for both 'id' and 'ssn'
      }
    }

    print "\n\n########################################################################################################\n\n";
    // now, try it without prepared statements

    $this->m->db->prepare("DELETE FROM {$this->m->db->library}.SelMaster");
    $this->m->db->execute();

    foreach($data as $record) {
      list($keys,$placeholders,$vals) = $this->m->parametersForInsert($record);
      $query = sprintf(
        "SELECT %s FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO {$this->m->db->library}.selmaster (%s) VALUES('%s'))",
        $this->m->map['id'],
        implode(',',$keys),
        implode("','",$vals)
        );
      print "\n$query  " . implode(',',$vals);
      $this->m->db->prepare($query);
      $this->m->db->execute();

      if($row = $this->m->nextRecord()) {
        print "\n";
        print_r($row);
      }
    }




  }
```

## The results

Notice the parameterized queries don't get a result on Bruce Wayne, Ben Grimm, Carter Hall, Martin Stein, and Luke Cage; yet the unparameterized version gets results for all:

```
Loading 001_crudClassTest
PHPUnit 6.0.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

R                                                                  1 / 1 (100%)
SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  001110001,Billy,Batson,Billy Batson
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1110001
    [ssn] => 1110001
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  001110002,Steve,Rogers,Steve Rogers
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1110002
    [ssn] => 1110002
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110003,Hank,McCoy,Hank McCoy
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110003
    [ssn] => 111110003
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110004,Bruce,Wayne,Bruce Wayne
SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110005,Selina,Kyle,Selina Kyle
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110005
    [ssn] => 111110005
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110006,Scott,Summers,Scott Summers
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110006
    [ssn] => 111110006
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110007,Matthew,Murdock,Matthew Murdock
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110007
    [ssn] => 111110007
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110008,Slade,Wilson,Slade Wilson
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110008
    [ssn] => 111110008
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110009,Emma,Frost,Emma Frost
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110009
    [ssn] => 111110009
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110010,Alan,Scott,Alan Scott
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110010
    [ssn] => 111110010
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110011,Bruce,Banner,Bruce Banner
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110011
    [ssn] => 111110011
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110012,Wally,West,Wally West
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110012
    [ssn] => 111110012
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?))  111110013,Richard,Reeds,Richard Reeds,3
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110013
    [ssn] => 111110013
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110014,Barry,Allen,Barry Allen
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110014
    [ssn] => 111110014
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110015,Ben,Grimm,Ben Grimm
SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?))  111110016,Peter,Parker,Peter Parker,2
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110016
    [ssn] => 111110016
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?))  111110017,Clark,Kent,Clark Kent,1
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110017
    [ssn] => 111110017
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110018,Carter,Hall,Carter Hall
SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110019,Martin,Stein,Martin Stein
SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?))  111110020,Dick,Grayson,Dick Grayson
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110020
    [ssn] => 111110020
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?))  111110021,Luke,Cage,Luke Cage,4
SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID,CONTCTID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?))  111110022,Tony,Stark,Tony Stark,5,1
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110022
    [ssn] => 111110022
)


########################################################################################################


SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('001110001','Billy','Batson','Billy Batson'))  001110001,Billy,Batson,Billy Batson
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1110001
    [ssn] => 1110001
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('001110002','Steve','Rogers','Steve Rogers'))  001110002,Steve,Rogers,Steve Rogers
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1110002
    [ssn] => 1110002
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110003','Hank','McCoy','Hank McCoy'))  111110003,Hank,McCoy,Hank McCoy
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110003
    [ssn] => 111110003
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110004','Bruce','Wayne','Bruce Wayne'))  111110004,Bruce,Wayne,Bruce Wayne
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110004
    [ssn] => 111110004
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110005','Selina','Kyle','Selina Kyle'))  111110005,Selina,Kyle,Selina Kyle
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110005
    [ssn] => 111110005
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110006','Scott','Summers','Scott Summers'))  111110006,Scott,Summers,Scott Summers
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110006
    [ssn] => 111110006
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110007','Matthew','Murdock','Matthew Murdock'))  111110007,Matthew,Murdock,Matthew Murdock
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110007
    [ssn] => 111110007
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110008','Slade','Wilson','Slade Wilson'))  111110008,Slade,Wilson,Slade Wilson
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110008
    [ssn] => 111110008
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110009','Emma','Frost','Emma Frost'))  111110009,Emma,Frost,Emma Frost
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110009
    [ssn] => 111110009
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110010','Alan','Scott','Alan Scott'))  111110010,Alan,Scott,Alan Scott
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110010
    [ssn] => 111110010
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110011','Bruce','Banner','Bruce Banner'))  111110011,Bruce,Banner,Bruce Banner
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110011
    [ssn] => 111110011
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110012','Wally','West','Wally West'))  111110012,Wally,West,Wally West
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110012
    [ssn] => 111110012
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES('111110013','Richard','Reeds','Richard Reeds','3'))  111110013,Richard,Reeds,Richard Reeds,3
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110013
    [ssn] => 111110013
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110014','Barry','Allen','Barry Allen'))  111110014,Barry,Allen,Barry Allen
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110014
    [ssn] => 111110014
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110015','Ben','Grimm','Ben Grimm'))  111110015,Ben,Grimm,Ben Grimm
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110015
    [ssn] => 111110015
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES('111110016','Peter','Parker','Peter Parker','2'))  111110016,Peter,Parker,Peter Parker,2
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110016
    [ssn] => 111110016
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES('111110017','Clark','Kent','Clark Kent','1'))  111110017,Clark,Kent,Clark Kent,1
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110017
    [ssn] => 111110017
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110018','Carter','Hall','Carter Hall'))  111110018,Carter,Hall,Carter Hall
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110018
    [ssn] => 111110018
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110019','Martin','Stein','Martin Stein'))  111110019,Martin,Stein,Martin Stein
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110019
    [ssn] => 111110019
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME) VALUES('111110020','Dick','Grayson','Dick Grayson'))  111110020,Dick,Grayson,Dick Grayson
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110020
    [ssn] => 111110020
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID) VALUES('111110021','Luke','Cage','Luke Cage','4'))  111110021,Luke,Cage,Luke Cage,4
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110021
    [ssn] => 111110021
)

SELECT SSN FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO test.selmaster (SSN,FNAME,LNAME,FULLNAME,SPOUSEID,CONTCTID) VALUES('111110022','Tony','Stark','Tony Stark','5','1'))  111110022,Tony,Stark,Tony Stark,5,1
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 111110022
    [ssn] => 111110022
)


Time: 1.94 seconds, Memory: 10.00MB

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Risky: 1.
```

---

Each run produces the same failures.  Changing the order of the inserts causes different records to fail to return `id` (failure doesn't follow record being inserted)

Why am I not getting consistent results with the parameterized queries?

---

#### Update

As per http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1019633 I tried deleting the SQL package which is more or less a cache of prepared statements.

After deleting the package, the test worked ONCE.  Then it went back to the squirrely results.  Each time I delete the package, the test will work one time.

Comment: Query appears to be missing a parenthesis SELECT id FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO {table} ({fields}) VALUES (?,? ... ?)

Comment: Sorry, typo.  It's correct in the code.

Comment: Are there any database errors that are occurring? I'm not sure that its likely but read the section on error handling here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_selectvalueinsert.html

Comment: When it fails, does the record get inserted and you just don't get a result or is there no data in the table as well?

Comment: The insert works; the select is intermittent.

Comment: @DavidButtrick There are no database errors reported.

Comment: To try and narrow things down, have you tried it using NEW TABLE instead of FINAL TABLE?  Do you have any triggers or referential integrity checks on this table?

Comment: There are no triggers, cursors, transactions, etc other that whatever db2 does on its own.  I am not familiar with `NEW TABLE`; I used `FINAL TABLE` as a result of googling...  `NEW TABLE` gives same results.

Comment: Can you always see the new row if you do a DSPPFM on the target table? (remembering that it may be going into an existing deleted row gap, if your table definition allows this)? If so, can you see it if you do a generic SELECT on the target table?

Comment: @MandyShaw I'm not sure what DSPPFM is telling me, but I do see the rows were inserted, and in the order that I would expect.  And a `select * from selmaster` always shows the rows in question; I just didn't get an ID when I inserted them.

Comment: OK thanks. Can't see the DDL for your selmaster table, could you provide that please? Incidentally there do seem to be some APAR's for similar-ish situations in DB2 on other platforms, e.g. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC52300, which makes me think this might possibly be a genuine bug.

Comment: I'm out of ideas at this point.  I tried to look around for a DB2/PHP equivalent of MySql's SQL_NO_CACHE but I couldn't find anything.  I would have to agree with @MandyShaw that it is probably a genuine bug.